# Error on Javascript code querying SharePoint list

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to return the contents of a SharePoint list to a HTML page using a JavaScript Query and JSON.

The line:

```
var query = "**http://collaboration-xxx/sites/it/SystemInventory/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Knownissues?$select=DeviceID,Title**
```

does return the DeviceID and Title in browser.

However I don't quite know how I should construct the var query to return results from all the columns. What I've got is:

```
**var query = " xxx/sites/it/SystemInventory/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Knownissues?$expand=Knownissues&$filter=DeviceID eq " + window.DeviceId + "";**
```

I've copied the `'windowsDeviceId'` from a previous file which did work. Just having the first var query doesn't return anything and the second returns the attached screen grab. [Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HesOY.png).

The SharePoint columns are: Title, ServiceStatus, Devicetype and DeviceID

JavaScript:

```
function getDeviceKnownIssues() {

  var txtTitle = "";
  var txtStatus = "";
//var ServiceStatus = "";
//var Devicetype = "";
//var query = "http://collaboration-xxx/sites/it/SystemInventory/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Knownissues?$select=DeviceID,Title", 

var query = "http://collaboration-xxx.com/sites/it/SystemInventory/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Knownissues?$expand=Knownissues&$filter=DeviceID eq " + window.DeviceId + "";
var call = $.ajax({
        url: query,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }       
    });
call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
$.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
        var tempID = result.DeviceId;
        var tempTitle = result.Title;
        var StatusType = ServiceStatus;
        txtTitle = txtTitle + "<p><a href='/sites/it/SystemInventory/SitePages/Service%20Catalogue.aspx?did=" + tempID + "'>" + tempTitle + "</a></p>";
        txtStatus = "<p>" + StatusType  + "</p>";
    });
   $('#knowntitle').append($(txtTitle));
   $('#servivestatus').append(txtStatus);

});
call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
    alert("Error retrieving data: " + jqXHR.responseText);
});

}
```

HTML

```
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"      
xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"><head>

<script src="/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="/it/SystemInventory/SiteAssets/scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="/sites/it/SystemInventory/SiteAssets/getDevices.js"></script>
<script  
src="/sites/it/SystemInventory/SiteAssets/getDeviceDetails.js"></script>

 <script 
src="/sites/it/SystemInventory/SiteAssets/getDeviceKnownIssues.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function parseQueryString(queryString)
{
var params = {}, queries, temp, i, l;
queries = queryString.split("&");
for ( i = 0, l = queries.length; i < l; i++ ) {
    temp = queries[i].split('=');
    params[temp[0]] = temp[1];
 }
return params;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
function getDeviceID() {
    if(typeof parseQueryString === "function") {
        if(window.location.href.indexOf("?") >= 0) {
            var qs = parseQueryString(window.location.href.split("?")[1])
            window.DeviceId = qs.did;
            getDeviceDetails();
            getDeviceKnownIssues();
        }
    }
}
getDeviceID();
getDevices();

 });


</script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-    style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
<tr>
 <td class="tg-yw4l">
    <h1>Devices</h1>
    <div id="devices">
    </div>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">
    <h1>Device Details</h1>
    <div id="devicedetails">
    </div>
   </td>
   <td class="tg-yw4l">
<h1>Device Overview</h1> 
    <div id="deviceoverview">
     <div id="devicekind">   
    </div>
  </td>
  </tr>


</table>

<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">
    <h1>Accessories</h1>
    <div id="deviceacc">

    </div>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">
    <h1>Typical Usage</h1>

    <div id="deviceuse">
    </div>
    </td>
<td class="tg-yw4l">
<h1>Spare Cell</h1> 
    <div id=" ">



    </div>
</td>
</tr>




</table>
Known Issues
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
   <td class="tg-yw4l">
     <h1>Title</h1>
    <div id="knowntitle">

    </div>
</td>
<td class="tg-yw4l">
    <h1>Service Status</h1>

    <div id="servivestatus">
    </div>
</td>
<td class="tg-yw4l">
<h1>Device Type</h1> 
    <div id=" ">



    </div>
</td>
  </tr>




</table>
```

Comment: The error states that there's a type mismatch between string and integer for DeviceId. A better and easier Approach might be using the [REST services](http://spmavericks.com/2014/11/10/get-list-data-using-rest-jquery-sharepoint-2013/)...

Comment: If deviceID is a text field, try adding single quotes around the `window.deviceID` like this: `var query = "http://collaboration-xxx.com/sites/it/SystemInventory/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Knownissues?$expand=Knownissues&$filter=DeviceID eq '" + window.DeviceId + "'";`

Comment: I want to stick with json to be honest. I'd be happy to get the DeviceID and Title to show on the HTML page as a starter.

Comment: Thanks Mike. That returns a different error: "Error retrieving data: 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR".

Comment: make sure you are using the internal names of the columns, not the display names

Comment: @Dazza What types of columns (in SharePoint) are Title, ServiceStatus, Devicetype and DeviceID?

Comment: Title is a text column, Service Status is a choice, Devicetype is a choice and DeviceID is a text column

Comment: FYI: You can ditch that query parameter code and use SP functions: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159289/what-does-this-code-getquerystringparameter-do